# Is there a log file for tests that are run during maven build life cycle?

Tags: eclipse, maven, junit

When I run mvn clean install, it runs my tests and 2 of them fail. When I run them on their own as junit tests, they pass. It only tells me that they failed during the mvn clean install and not why they failed. I'm wondering if there's a log for the tests run during the build lifecycle that I'm not aware of. Or do I need to set up my own logging system for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a look at the test report:

```
target/surfire-reports/index.html
```